# How to convert from String to Int in Json.Decoder

Tags: json, elm

Here's my decoder:

```
decodeData : Json.Decoder (Id, String)
decodeData =
  Json.at ["data", "0"]
    <| Json.object2 (,)
      ("id" := Json.int)
      ("label" := Json.string)
```

The `id` should logically be `Int` however my backend sends it as `String` (e.g. we get `"1"` instead of `1`).

How can I cast the decoded value to `Int`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

... and to answer myself :) I found the solution in this [Flickr](http://elm-lang.org/examples/flickr) example

```
decodeData : Json.Decoder (Id, String)
decodeData =
  let number =
    Json.oneOf [ Json.int, Json.customDecoder Json.string String.toInt ]
  in
    Json.at ["data", "0"]
      <| Json.object2 (,)
        ("id" := number)
        ("label" := Json.string)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Elm-0.18

Use [`parseInt`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/json-extra/2.7.0/Json-Decode-Extra#parseInt) decoder ([source](https://github.com/elm-community/json-extra/blob/2.7.0/src/Json/Decode/Extra.elm#L388)):

```elm
decodeString parseInt """ "123" """
```

Here is [tutorial](https://www.brianthicks.com/post/2017/01/13/create-custom-json-decoders-in-elm-018/) about custom decoders, like for date. Reuse [`fromResult`](https://github.com/elm-community/json-extra/blob/2.7.0/src/Json/Decode/Extra.elm#L368) approach.

Answer (score 0):

The validated answer is obsolete. Here is an answer for Elm 0.19:

```
dataDecoder : Decoder Data
dataDecoder =
    Decode.map2 Data
        (Decode.field "id" (Decode.string |> Decode.andThen stringToIntDecoder))
        (Decode.field "label" Decode.string)


stringToIntDecoder : String -> Decoder Int
stringToIntDecoder year =
    case String.toInt year of
        Just value ->
            Decode.succeed value

        Nothing ->
            Decode.fail "Invalid integer"
```

And an [executable example](https://ellie-app.com/5LKDvHfdRVZa1)