# How to convert from String to Int in Json.Decoder in elm-core > 5.0.0

Tags: json, elm

This is idential to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444046/how-to-convert-from-string-to-int-in-json-decoder), except elm has changed since then so that answer is no longer valid (in particular there is no longer a `Decode.customDecoder` object).

How do you do this same thing in elm-core > 5.0.0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert from String to Int in Json.Decoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444046/how-to-convert-from-string-to-int-in-json-decoder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own custom decoder by using `succeed` and `fail` from `Json.Decode`. I changed the argument order below to make it chainable.

**Edit**: separated decoder concerns from result concerns.

```
import Json.Decode as Json
import Result


-- // This is a Result helper function that could be used elsewhere.
-- // Currently, there is no Result.either in Elm core.
eitherR : (x -> b) -> (a -> b) -> Result x a -> b
eitherR fErr fOk result =
    case result of
        Err x ->
            fErr x

        Ok a ->
            fOk a


customDecoder : (a -> Result String b) -> Json.Decoder a -> Json.Decoder b
customDecoder fResult decoder =
    decoder |> Json.andThen (fResult >> eitherR Json.fail Json.succeed)
```

Plugging this in to the linked question...

```
let number =
    Json.oneOf [ Json.int, Json.string |> customDecoder String.toInt ]
```

Here's another example use. This is a version of `onChange` which converts the value to an integer. Mainly useful for `select` when you know the option value is an Int.

```
import Html
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import String


onChangeInt : (Int -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onChangeInt fMsg =
    on "change" (targetValue |> customDecoder String.toInt |> Json.map fMsg)
```

Note that `targetValue` is defined in the Html.Events module:

```
targetValue : Decoder String
```

Comment: There actually is a function like your `eitherR` in `Result.Extra`, [`Result.Extra.unpack`]( http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/result-extra/latest/Result-Extra#unpack)

Answer (score 6):

One way to do it (as of Elm 0.18 and core 5.0) would be like this:

```
stringIntDecoder : Decoder Int
stringIntDecoder =
    Json.Decode.map (\str -> String.toInt (str) |> Result.withDefault 0) Json.Decode.string
```

The `String.toInt` function from the standard library takes a string and attempts to convert it to an integer, returning a Result. `Result.withDefault` does what its name implies -- you give it some default value and a result, and if the Result is `Ok x` you get `x` but if it's `Err _` you get the default value you supplied, here 0. You could instead write a function to handle a Result yourself if you like and pass that function in instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a default, I want it to fail if it doesn't succeed!

Comment: @vitiral Pass in your own result-handling function there instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`parseInt`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/json-extra/2.7.0/Json-Decode-Extra#parseInt) decoder ([source](https://github.com/elm-community/json-extra/blob/2.7.0/src/Json/Decode/Extra.elm#L388)):

```elm
decodeString parseInt """ "123" """
```

Look at the [tutorial](https://www.brianthicks.com/post/2017/01/13/create-custom-json-decoders-in-elm-018/) about custom decoders, like for date. Reuse [`fromResult`](https://github.com/elm-community/json-extra/blob/2.7.0/src/Json/Decode/Extra.elm#L368) approach.

Read about [function composition (<<)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441648/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-elm), which is used in `parseInt` function.

Answer (score 1):

Given that in the comment to the other answer, you state the need to embrace possible failure, you could use a Maybe.

```
stringIntDecoder : Decoder (Maybe Int)
stringIntDecoder =
    Json.Decode.map (String.toInt >> Result.toMaybe) Json.Decode.string
```

Or

```
stringIntDecoder : Decoder (Result String Int)
stringIntDecoder =
    Json.Decode.map (String.toInt) Json.Decode.string
```

Comment: but that will cause the field to be "Nothing" -- it will not cause a Decoder error! (`Decode.fail`)

Comment: then just skip the `Result.toMaybe`

Comment: that doesn't type check

Comment: Please restate what json you get and what results you want

Answer (score 0):

For Elm 0.19 using the documentation for [targetValue](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Events#targetValue), the code becomes:

```
import Html.Events
import Json.Decode

onIntInput : (Int -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onIntInput tagger =
    Html.Events.stopPropagationOn "input" <|
        Json.Decode.map alwaysStop (Json.Decode.map tagger targetIntValue)

targetIntValue : Decoder Int
targetIntValue =
  Json.Decode.at ["target", "value"] Json.Decode.string |> Json.Decode.andThen (\value ->
    case String.toInt value of
      Just number -> Json.Decode.succeed number
      Nothing -> Json.Decode.fail "not a number")

alwaysStop : a -> (a, Bool)
alwaysStop x =
  (x, True)
```

and you can then use onIntInput where you used onInput.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that avoids having to choose a sketchy default value:

```
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (Decoder)

decodeIntString : Decoder (Maybe Int)
decodeIntString =
    Decode.map String.toInt Decode.string


decodeMaybeFail : Maybe a -> Decoder a
decodeMaybeFail val =
    case val of
        Just a ->
            Decode.succeed a

        Nothing ->
            Decode.fail "'Nothing' value can't be decoded"
```

You then use it with

```
Decode.andThen decodeMaybeFail decodeIntString
```

(this is of type `Decoder Int`, so you use it like you would use `Decode.int`)

Not obvious at first, but it illustrates how to break this problem down into simple small steps.

In my opinion a function `decodeMaybeFail : Maybe a -> Decoder a` should be in the standard `Json.Decode` module.